# Developer Internal Training Class Management Software

Tags: software-development, scheduling

## Developer Internal Training Class Management Software

My organization currently offers internal developer training classes (e.g. unit testing, Docker, AWS) for developers who want to learn and grow. We currently manage these classes through a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet.

We are looking for software that will improve the class creation and signup process and provide analytics and reporting to measure the results of the classes.

### Minimum Requirements

#### Technical Specs

- Web based

#### Class Creation

Ability to create one time and recurring classes with the following fields.

- Title
- Date and Time
- Description
- Size
- Teacher Name
- Location
- Topic(s)

#### Class Signup

- Ability to signup for a class
- Ability to signup for a waitlist if class is full

#### Class Viewing

- Ability to view all available and past classes
- Ability to search for classes by keywords
- Ability to filter classes by topic
- Ability to see all classes you created
- Ability to see all classes you signed up for

#### Reporting and Analytics

Reporting to answer the following questions.

1. How many classes are currently available?
2. How many classes were taught in a given time period?
3. How many classes is a given user teaching?
4. How many classes is a given user taking?
5. How many classes has a given user taught in a given time period?
6. How many classes has a given user taken in a given time period?
7. What percentage of users are taking classes?
8. How frequently are users signing up for classes?

### Optional Requirements

- User notifications
- Surveys
- Commenting on classes

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any existing software that meets those requirements. But you could use [Airtable](https://airtable.com/) to improve your training class management.

### Proof of Concept

I've [created a proof of concept](https://airtable.com/shrbR0OVk4wou8XED/tblB0t3pJnxqzXVrI/viwyxpnYk8eucm4A2?blocks=bip2DS92qHWJlq0Ii) based on your requirements. Feel free to copy the base.

[image]

### Additional Screenshots

**Class Gallery View**

[image: Class gallery view]

https://airtable.com/shrIDYC2u1cmtFh5C/tblB0t3pJnxqzXVrI?blocks=hide

**Class Calendar View**

[image: Class calendar view]

https://airtable.com/shrFjVb9HJTdZzBcl/tblB0t3pJnxqzXVrI?blocks=hide

**Class Signup Form**

[image: Class signup form]

https://airtable.com/shro11YpLfh0ysxKZ